# PHP compare dates in registration form

Tags: php, date

I have a registration form in which I need to verify that the user is over 18 years old (the user fills in his date of birth by selecting the values from 3 drop down menus, day, month, year). Which is the best way to do it?
I'm trying to use mktime and subtracting the date of birth from the current date but can't get it right.

Comment: Please post the code that you have so far.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is subtracting giving the wrong age? Are you not getting the right date from the input? Is your current date wrong? You need to be specific in what exactly is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%y');
```

The above code returns the result in years, you can check with the years in a conditional loop to allow users for registration...

Answer (score 3):

I'd use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php), and do something along the following lines:

```
<?php
$year  = (int) $_POST['year'];
$month = (int) $_POST['month'];
$day   = (int) $_POST['day'];

$now = new DateTime();
$dob = new DateTime("$year-$month-$day");

$age = (int) $now->diff($dob)->format("%y");

if ($age < 18) {
    // Denied
}
```

Working with dates are usually problematic due to edge cases, so I find it best to leave it to libraries designed and developed by people who have considered the edge cases.

Comment: +1 for a good answer. However, note that the `DateTime->diff()` method is only available from PHP5.3, so if you're stuck on 5.2 (or worse!), you'll need to use something else.